# I am Having some trouble getting coverage for my class

Tags: apex, unit-test, class, code-coverage

Im trying to write a testclass but my coverage remains 0 Why is this?

Class:

```
global class RenewalValueOpp  implements Schedulable{
  global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
    List<Opportunity> RenewalValue=[SELECT Id,Opportunity.Name, (SELECT Id FROM Orders__r) 
                                    FROM Opportunity 
                                    WHERE CreatedBy.Name='Mart man' AND CreatedDate=TODAY AND Type='Renewal'];
    system.debug('RenewalValue van Oppottunity'+RenewalValue);
    for(Opportunity r : RenewalValue){
      double TotOrder = 0;
      List<Order__c> OrderAmount =[SELECT id, Order_Amount__c FROM Order__c WHERE Opportunity_Name__r.Id=:r.Id];
      System.debug('OrderAmount '+ OrderAmount);
        for(Order__c o : OrderAmount){ 
          TotOrder += o.Order_Amount__c; 
        }  
       r.Renewal_Value__c=TotOrder;
       System.debug('r.Renewal_Value__c   TotOrder'+ r.Renewal_Value__c);
       Update r;
     }
  }
}
```

Original test class:

```
@isTest 

public class RenewalValueOppTestClass{  

    @isTest
    private static void RenewalValueOppTestClass(){

        Profile prof = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
        User u = new User(firstname = 'Mart',
                            lastName = 'man',
                            email = 'Mart.man@test.org',
                            Username = 'Mart.man@test.org.1234567',
                            EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1',
                            Alias ='tuser',
                            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                            ProfileId = prof.Id);
        insert u;

        System.runAs(u) {
            Account acct = new Account ( Name='Testaccount',Customer_Profile__c='Wolters Kluwer');
            insert acct;
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name = 'TestOpp', Type='Renewal',AccountId=acct.Id);
            insert opp;
            Contact cont = new Contact(Lastname='Testname', Initials__c='A.A.', AccountId=acct.Id, Email='testcontact@test.nl', Title='Consultant' , Department='Academic');
            insert cont;
            Order__c ord1 = new Order__c(Account_Name__c=acct.Id, Delegate_Admin__c=cont.LastName, Number_of_Users__c=5,  CurrencyIsoCode='EUR - Euro',Order_Amount__c=1500 );
            insert ord1;
            Order__c ord2 = new Order__c(Account_Name__c=acct.Id, Delegate_Admin__c=cont.LastName, Number_of_Users__c=10,  CurrencyIsoCode='EUR - Euro',Order_Amount__c=500  );
            insert ord2;

            List<Order__c> OrderAmount =[SELECT id, Order_Amount__c FROM Order__c WHERE Opportunity_Name__r.Id=:opp.Name];


            double TotOrder = 0;
            Test.startTest();
            for(Order__c o : OrderAmount){ 
                TotOrder += o.Order_Amount__c; 
            }  
            opp.Renewal_Value__c=TotOrder;  
            Test.stopTest();

            System.assertEquals(opp.Renewal_Value__c,2000);

        }
    }  
}
```

+edit: after incorporating suggestions from answers

Testclass:

```
@isTest
public class RenewalValueOppTestClass{  

    @isTest
    private static void RenewalValueOppTestClass(){

        Profile prof = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
        User u = new User(firstname = 'Mart',
                            lastName = 'man',
                            email = 'Mart.man@test.org',
                            Username = 'Mart.man@test.org.1234567',
                            EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1',
                            Alias ='tuser',
                            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                            ProfileId = prof.Id);
        insert u;

        System.runAs(u) {
            Account acct = new Account ( Name='Testaccount',Customer_Profile__c='Wolters Kluwer');
            insert acct;
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name = 'TestOpp', Type='Renewal',AccountId=acct.Id);
            insert opp;
            Contact cont = new Contact(Lastname='Testname', Initials__c='A.A.', AccountId=acct.Id, Email='testcontact@test.nl', Title='Consultant' , Department='Academic');
            insert cont;
            Order__c ord1 = new Order__c(Account_Name__c=acct.Id, Delegate_Admin__c=cont.LastName, Number_of_Users__c=5,  CurrencyIsoCode='EUR - Euro',Order_Amount__c=1500 );
            insert ord1;
            Order__c ord2 = new Order__c(Account_Name__c=acct.Id, Delegate_Admin__c=cont.LastName, Number_of_Users__c=10,  CurrencyIsoCode='EUR - Euro',Order_Amount__c=500  );
            insert ord2;

            List<Order__c> OrderAmount =[SELECT id, Order_Amount__c FROM Order__c WHERE Opportunity_Name__r.Id=:opp.Name];


            double TotOrder = 0;
            Test.startTest();
            for(Order__c o : OrderAmount){ 
              TotOrder += o.Order_Amount__c; 
            }  
            opp.Renewal_Value__c=TotOrder;  
            Test.stopTest();

            // Start of new code
            test.startTest();
            RenewalValueOpp schOpp =new RenewalValueOpp();
            String sch = '0  00 1 3 * ?';
            system.schedule('Test', sch, schOpp);
            test.stopTest();
            // End of new code

            System.assertEquals(opp.Renewal_Value__c,2000);

        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Your not getting coverage because the second - `test.startTest();` will throw a runtime error and thus your batch code is never called. Also, the `stoptest` needs to be AFTER you call `system.schedule`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create Opportunity records with the user name `Mart man`. Also, `CreatedBy.Name='Mart man'` criteria is very fragile, as there can be duplicate user names in an org.

So, first create a user record with that name and create Opportunity record with that user and then use `System.runAs(userId)` to test the scenarios.

```
User tuser = new User(  firstname = 'Mart',
                            lastName = 'man',
                            email = 'Mart.man@test.org',
                            Username = 'Mart.man@test.org.1234567',
                            EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1',
                            Alias ='tuser',
                            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                            ProfileId = profId);


insert tuser;
```

Comment: I added the user and am running as but still dont get any coverage? See my edited code above

Comment: Hey Santanu. Can you help me with an issue?

Answer (score 4):

You have a query in a loop in your global class which should be removed.

As is, your test class shouldn't <strike>even compile</strike> run successfully because you use `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` twice in it (we're only allowed to call the startTest/stopTest methods once per test method. It produces a runtime error `System.FinalException: Testing already started` if you try this).

Looking at the revision history for your test class, it seems you encountered the fairly common testing trap of *not actually calling the code that you're trying to test*.

**You only gain coverage for code that is executed as part of a test method**. So if you're not getting coverage, then your code isn't being executed. After you fix your test so that it actually calls `RenewalValueOpp.execute()`, figuring out what to do at is a matter of looking at the code you're trying to test.

- Do you have an `if()` statement that you need to satisfy to execute some code?

  - Adjust your test setup so that the data you'll have when executing
    that portion of code will match the conditions.
- Do you have a query that you loop over?

  - You'll need to insert some records in your test setup (that match the criteria in the `WHERE` clause) so your query returns something to loop over

One last tip, you don't need to actually schedule your `execute` method to test it. `RenewalValueOpp.execute(null)` works just fine.

Comment: Using Test.stopTest() and Test.startTest() multiple times per method will produce a runtime error instead of a compile-time error. So it is still possible that this class compiles.

Comment: @salesforce-hacker Right you are, updating my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You must have to add class reference in test class please add this piece of code in you test class. hope it will help you!

```
        test.startTest();
        RenewalValueOpp schOpp =new RenewalValueOpp();
        String sch = '0  00 1 3 * ?';
        system.schedule('Test', sch, schOpp);
        test.stopTest();
```

Regards, Akshay

Comment: I am quite new to schedulers. I tried your solution see edited code but I am still not getting any coverage?

Comment: Please let me know your test run status is successful or unsuccessful. if unsuccessful send me the error you get.

Comment: I found one error please add StageName and CloseDate when you create Opportunity these two are mandatory fields.

Comment: I added those but get: Insert failed. Adres is mandatory. I see now if I try to insert a new account its needed but It doesnt show the red lines as a mandatory

Comment: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION  this type of error fetching in these condition like any triggeror validation rule written on Address fields.

Comment: Account and Contact have Address field. please make sure. if you have any validation criteria. Thanks

Comment: I had to fill schipping & billing adres on account but get Invalid Id on name contact?